# How is Pricing calculated in Heroku PostGres Addon

Tags: heroku

Heroku has now upgraded its plans. So I have a doubt on the Heroku postgres Mini plan. I have a site which uses the heroku postgres database. The site is just for my practice and in my free time i work or use it. The Heroku upgrade for mini plan reads like "Heroku prorates costs to the second. For example, if you have 1 Mini Postgres database provisioned for 1 hour, it costs you ~$0.004."

What exactly does provision mean over here? Since I have a postgres database addon does that mean it will run all 24 hours? Or hours will count only when I open my website which fetches data from the DB or when i connect to my database, does the hours begin to count. Please help!

Comment: Have you tried asking the vendor?

Comment: Sadly with a free account the vendor does not allow raising support requests to them. They direct you to the StackOverflow communirty page @mustaccio

Comment: Did they actually send you here with a _pricing_ question?

Comment: @Joy Agreed with mustaccio. Any company selling a service will always address your questions on pricing for that service, as it's an opportunity for a sale. Please speak with the vendor and close your question here.